# Serialize JSON propertly

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am trying to serialize a string array into JSON and I am using Newtonsoft JSON.Net for this but the output is wrong and I don't know how to serialize it properly.

I use this code:

```
string[] subscriptions = new string[] { "downloads" }; 
string[] exclusion = new string[] { "REFRESH_CONTENT" };
var toSend = new string[][] { subscriptions, exclusion };
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toSend);
```

And I get this result:

```
params: [[\"downloads\"],[\"REFRESH_CONTENT\"]]
```

But I need to get this result:

```
params: [\"[\\\"downloads\\\"]\",\"[\\\"REFRESH_CONTENT\\\"]\"]
or without escaped strings (to be sure there is no error in the line above):
params: ["[\"downloads\"]","[\"REFRESH_CONTENT\"]"]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectations are wrong. Your `toSend` is an array of string arrays. And this is what the serialization produces. If you want to get an array of strings, you have to create one:

```
var toSend = new string[] {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(subscriptions), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exclusion)};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toSend);
```

But this way, you'll have to parse each element of the array at the receiver side.